# Filter Core Data objects by relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, one-to-many, entity-relationship

I have two objects: `Category` and `Item`. An `Item` has a `name` field, `price` field, and `quantity` field. A `Category` has a `name` field. A category also has many `Items`. When I access my tableView of `categories` I want to display all the `items` related to that `category`. Below is my code of how I'm setting the relationship when a new `Item` is added and also when a `category` is fetched to display all its items. Am I not saving the relationship correctly?

### Saving Relationship

```
func saveItem(name: String, quantity: Int, price: String) {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Item", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let item = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
    var error: NSError?

    item.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    item.setValue(quantity, forKey: "quantity")
    item.setValue(price, forKey: "price")
    item.setValue(selectedCategory, forKey: "category")
    // selectedCategory: the parent of this new item
    selectedCategory.setValue(NSOrderedSet(object: item), forKey: "item")
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
    else {
        items.append(item)
        self.fetchCategories("")
    }
}
```

### fetching items of category

```
func fetchItems() {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Item")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category = %@", category?.valueForKey("name") as! String)
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        items = results

    }
    else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

### my data model

[image]
[image]

Comment: When you save the item, what is selectedCategory? How is it created?

Comment: `selectedCategory` is a Category of my data model, the Category that I want the Item to be a child of. It's set when segued into this view.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? In your fetchRequest predicate you refer to category?.valueForKey. Are you sure that returns a value?

Comment: No errors. It just runs, saves the item to Core Data, but It's referenced in every Category. And yes that value is printing out fine.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `item` relationship is the inverse of the `category` relationship, you do not need to set both.  If you set the relationship one way, Core Data automatically does the other:

```
item.setValue(selectedCategory, forKey: "category")
```

So the following lines are not required...

```
// selectedCategory: the parent of this new item
selectedCategory.setValue(NSOrderedSet(object: item), forKey: "item")
```

Also your predicate is wrong in the fetch - there is no need to use the `name` attribute in the predicate - CoreData will (under the hood) use its own primary key.  So amend this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category = %@", category?.valueForKey("name") as! String)
```

to this:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "category = %@", category!)
```